# ORA-01722: invalid number PLSQL IMPLICIT CURSOR

Tags: sql, plsql

```
BEGIN 
  FOR v_region_rec IN (SELECT region_name, c.country_name
                         FROM regions r
                         JOIN countries c
                           ON r.region_id = c.country_id)
  LOOP
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE (v_region_rec.region_name || '  |  ' ||  v_region_rec.country_name );
  END LOOP;
END;
```

ran this plsql statement but i really can't tell why its giving me the ORA-01722: invalid number

Comment: Names are unlikely to be numbers, so the more obvious culprit is the `join` condition.

Comment: Please edit your question and include a description of the COUNTRIES and REGIONS tables - in particular, the data types of all the fields used in this question. Thanks.

Comment: thanks just figure it out